# Should I backshift with "If you ever wondered..."?

Tags: tense, backshifting

Do I use present or past tense after the phrase "If you ever wondered"?

Examples:

> If you ever wondered what hell looks like, ...
>
> If you ever wondered what hell looked like, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, with an embedded question or statement in a past-tense sentence, the verb in the embedded part is also past:

> Where is he going? -> I wondered where he was going.

But when the question or statement is timeless, both present and past are possible:

> The Greek philosophers knew that the world is/was round.
>
> What does hell look like? -> Have you ever wondered what hell looks/looked like?

I find the past slightly more natural there: using the present puts emphasis on the fact that what is described is timeless or still continuing.